# How are expression and arguments ordered for execution?

Tags: c, printf, expression

So learning C by questing everything and understanding behavior of std library functions, I come across this:

In the following 2 codes;

Code1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

printf(" %d %d",printf("Hello"),printf("Bye"));

return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ByeHello 5 3

Code2:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

printf(" %d",printf("Hello")+printf("Bye"));

return 0;
}
```

Output:

> HelloBye 8

In the first program; the expressions seems to be executed from right to left however in second code the expressions are being executed from left to right. Why would this happen. How are expressions executed exactly?

Comment: The order is unspecified in both cases. Unspecified means that the compiler is free to do whatever is more convenient for it at that particular moment.

Comment: If you have `f(x) + g(y)` as an expression in C, I don't think there's any particular requirement for C to call `f` or `g` in any particular order. It's up to the compiler implementation. So you can't count on it. Similarly if you call `foo(f(x), g(x))`. The order could be anything. When C calls a function, arguments are pushed onto the stack in reverse order. So if you call `foo(x, y)`, then `y` is put on the stack first followed by `x`, then the call is made. But that doesn't mean it has to completely evaluate the expression of `g` before `f` for `foo(f(x), g(x))`.

Comment: Have a look at [Order of evaluation of operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112282/order-of-evaluation-of-operands).

Comment: [Also this previous case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31046816/2173917).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameter evaluation order before a function calling in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c)

Comment: This is not too broad to answer. I think it should be put on hold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of evaluation of function arguments are are not guaranteed to be in any order, i.e. order of evaluation is unspecified. They can evaluate in any order.

n1570-J.1 Unspecified behavior:

> -The order in which the function designator, arguments, and subexpressions within the arguments are evaluated in a function call (6.5.2.2).

6.5.2(p12):

> EXAMPLE In the function call
>
> ```
> (*pf[f1()]) (f2(), f3() + f4())
> ```
>
> the functions `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, and `f4` may be called in any order. [...]

Comment: [possible dupe, sir?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31046816/2173917)

Comment: @SouravGhosh; That's not the exact dupe but there is a close one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/376278/2455888), but an answer there explain it with the reference of C99. I didn't find any answer that gives quote from C11 standard about the order of evaluation of arguments of a function and that's why I didn't marked it as a dupe. It should be also noted that the link you are referring to and the one I am referring in this comment is more about the side-effects on the arguments and that makes the behavior of those codes are guaranteed to be undefined. .....

Comment: @SouravGhosh; .... In the present case the behavior of the program is **unspecified** while the cases discussed in the above links are **undefined**.